# mysql xtrabackup missing binary logs

Tags: mysql, backup, xtrabackup

It seems xtrabackup is not backing up binary logs, although it creates xtrabackup_binlog* with apparently correct information inside. 
Should the binary logs be copied manually beforehand or is this a bug?

Comment: xtrabackup is not supposed to copy binary logs. It creates a which is InnoDB redo log (similar to ib_logfile*) only. The file you see contains binlog coordinates so you can create a slave out of the backup copy.

Comment: so how are you supposed to start the slave without the binlogs? Create empty binlog index by hand?

Comment: you run CHANGE MASTER on the slave

Comment: Restored DB won't even start without the binlogs

Comment: I'll tell you more. On a slave binary log may be not enabled at all. I think you're confused about how replication works.

Comment: I don't want replication, I just want to perform backup/restore the correct way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15235/discussion-between-akuzminsky-and-sivann).

Answer (score 0):

When using `xtrabackup` the binary logs aren't copied per file (but in one binlogfile).
You need to restore this differently, see docs: [Preparing a Full Backup with innobackupex](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/preparing_a_backup_ibk.html).

Or, with more extensive explanations:

1. Percona documentation - [Prepare with xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/xtrabackup_bin/preparing_the_backup.html)
2. Percona documentation - [Restore with xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/xtrabackup_bin/restoring_a_backup.html)

In relation to your database not starting after restore, you might want to paste your `my.cnf` and server log `hostname.err`.